# React: Not able to render react-rating-star component with correct value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have ratings stored in cloud firestore, and so when the page loads, I want to grab the rating (if it exists) and display it to the user. However, it does not work as intended. Although I am able to retrieve the rating from firestore, the rating value doesn't show when I refresh/load the page. Below is a snippet from the return

```
<div className="musicTrackInfoDiv">
    <div className="musicTrackTitleAndArtist">
        <label className="musicTrackTitle" style={{display: 'block'}}>{track.name}</label>
        <label className="musicTrackArtist">{track.album?.artists[0].name}</label>
        <ReactStars
            value={Math.max(0, rating)}
            count={5}
            onChange={ratingChanged}
            size={24}
            isHalf={true}
            emptyIcon={<i className="far fa-star"></i>}
            halfIcon={<i className="fa fa-star-half-alt"></i>}
            fullIcon={<i className="fa fa-star"></i>}
            activeColor="#ffd700"
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

In my useEffect function, I am getting the rating value from firestore and using useState hooks, I use setRating to properly set the rating value.

```
const [rating, setRating] = useState(0);
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("userData").doc(spotifyId).get()
        .then((docSnap) => {
            const songInfo = docSnap.get(id.id);
            if (songInfo == undefined) {
                console.log("There was no saved musicEntry");
            } else {
                // put the post in the text area but check if it's undefined
                document.getElementById("textArea").value = songInfo.musicEntry ? songInfo.musicEntry : "";
                console.log("There was a saved music entry: " + songInfo.musicEntry);

                // check if there is a rating
                setRating(songInfo.rating ? songInfo.rating : 0);
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
}, [])
```

I've done a lot of testing, and yes, songInfo.rating exists as I am correctly retrieving the rating from firestore, when I console.log(songInfo.rating) it is 3, I just dont know why it doesn't show up when I render the component when the page loads.

Comment: I initialize it to 0

Comment: Yeahh i have, when I do that, it'll log 3 and so when I load the page, 3 stars should be filled, but it always shows 0.

Comment: Have you tried some simple debugging? Put `console.log("song rating", JSON.stringify(songInfo.rating))` before you call `setRating()`. What **exactly** does it show?

Comment: it says  "song rating 3"

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the `ReactStars` component (or a link to its documentation if you didn't write it). FYI you should definitely not be using DOM methods like `getElementById()` in a Recat app. Use state to drive changes. Also, you don't need a ternary to display `ReactStars`. Simply using one with `value={Math.max(0, ratings)}` should be enough

Comment: here is the documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-rating-stars-component

Comment: and ahh, im sorry, im pretty new to react and js in general, what should i be using instead of getElementById() to fill in my textArea component (answer only if u have time! appreciate all your help already), and yes, I will change the ternary

Comment: Do it the same way you've done `ratings`... create a state variable (`const [musicEntry, setMusicEntry] = useState("")`), use it in your `textArea` element (eg `<textarea value={musicEntry} />`) and call `setMusicEntry(songInfo.musicEntry)` where required

Comment: nice, thank you! just modified that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the `ReactStars` component. It does not react to changes to its `value` prop.

A work-around for this is to provide a `key` prop to force React to re-render the component when `rating` changes

```jsx
<ReactStars
  key={`stars_${rating}`}
  value={Math.max(0, rating)}
  count={5}
  onChange={ratingChanged}
  size={24}
  isHalf={true}
  emptyIcon={<i className="far fa-star"></i>}
  halfIcon={<i className="fa fa-star-half-alt"></i>}
  fullIcon={<i className="fa fa-star"></i>}
  activeColor="#ffd700"
/>
```

[image: Edit goofy-microservice-g2qd0i]

---

FYI this is a [reported issue](https://github.com/ertanhasani/react-stars/issues/16) on the component but there is currently no official fix.